# Inserting Checkbox values in database without unicode in django

Tags: django, unicode, checkbox

I am getting the values from checkbox field from django custom form as shown below

```
error = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices = Error)

[u'None', u'Error',u'Fixed']
```

Now when I am inserting the above values in database the value is taking the entire list in the db field. I want to get the values as `None,Error,Fixed` without `[]` brackets. Is there any magic in python for doing so? Please help me this will be really helpful for my reporting stuff. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by this way

```
 newstate = []
 state = [u'None', u'Error',u'Fixed']
 for i in state:
    newstate.append(str(i))
```

Now this gives the output

```
['None', 'Error','Fixed']
```

Now I am inserting the above values in database (this is for checkbox values captured from django form). At this stage I have one more problem, while retrieving the contents, I am getting in unicode

`k="['None', 'Error', 'Fixed']"`

I have solved this problem by using eval method. for converting the string to list

`new_list=eval(k)` which gives the output

`['None', 'Error','Fixed']`

My problem got solved. Thanks for giving the little clue. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Iterate over it](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).